# Getting error 1008 when trying to delete a message with my bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I use the command `=m p "some song"`
I'm getting this error when trying to get my bot to delete a message:

```
DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\poe-sieglind\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\poe-sieglind\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async MessageManager.delete (C:\poe-sieglind\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\MessageManager.js:205:5)
    at async Message.delete (C:\poe-sieglind\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:709:5) {
  method: 'delete',
  path: '/channels/357701531921022979/messages/882759166404489258',
  code: 10008,
  httpStatus: 404,
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}
```

The code in question is:

```
client.on("messageCreate", msg => {
    let borrar = false;
    let delay = 0;
    if (msg.author.username === 'Ayana') {
        delay = 10000;
        borrar = true;
    }
    if (msg.content.startsWith('=') || msg.content.startsWith('-')) {
        delay = 15000;
        borrar = true;
    }
    if (borrar) {
        setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), delay);
    }
}) // Borra comandos y respuestas de bots
```

I'm using:

```
discord js = 13.1.0
dotenv = 10.0.0
node = 16.8.0
npm = 7.21.0
```

The problem might be that the bot whose message I try to delete, deletes some messages from itself and that's why it can't delete it

Is there a way to detect if the message has been deleted or catch the error if it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found how to solve this:

```
function borrado(mensaje){
    if (mensaje.deletable){
        mensaje.delete()
    }
}
if (borrar) {
    setTimeout(() => borrado(msg), delay);
```

The function uses the method deletable to check if will be possible to delete the message and then proceeds